# Javascript, how does it work string to int use bitshift like '2' >> 0

Tags: javascript

I use bitshift want to conver String to bit, but I want to know how does it work. 

`"12345" >> 0  // int 12345`

I found '>>' only for deal with 32-bit things and will return a int. But I confuse how it is work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-signed-right-shift-operator), in `"12345" >> 0`, this happens:

1. `"12345"` is put through the specification's abstract [`ToInt32` function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-toint32):

   - ToInt32 runs it through [`ToNumber`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-tonumber) to coerce the string to a standard JavaScript number (an IEEE-754 double-precision binary floating-point value); it ends up being 12345
   - `ToInt32` then converts it to a 32-bit integer value; it ends up being...12345
2. That 32-bit integer is shifted...not at all because you used `>> 0`, so we still have 12345

> and will return a int

Sort of. If you stored the result in a variable, it would end up being a standard JavaScript number again (a double). The spec seems to allow for the possibility the int value would be used as-is if you combined this operation with others, though, which makes sense.

If your goal is just to force `"12345"` to be a number using the default coercion rules, `>> 0` is a fairly obscure and somewhat inefficient way to do it (not that the latter is likely to matter). The unary `+` is rather more direct and applies the same rules: `+"12345"`

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators),

> The operands of all bitwise operators are converted to signed 32-bit integers in two's complement format.

JS simply converts your string to a Number, and then shifts it by 0 position (read "does nothing").

This JS type conversion is pretty fun. You can also simply use unary `+` to convert your string to a number. This approach is a common practice, and looks much better than bitwise shifting.

```js
var str = "12345";
console.log(+str);
console.log(+str + 1);
```